# How to read the contents of a column, assign these values to new columns and fill them with the values of other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, match, reshape

I have the following data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(site=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B"), A=c("item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item3"),
               A_weight=c(4.2,4.2,6.1,6.4,8.5), A_numbers=c(1,2,8,5,2))
```

For each item `[x]` in column `A` I would like two new columns to be automaticaly created and named `"item[x]_weight"` and `"item[x]_numbers"`.
To each of these columns I want to assign the values of the `A_weight` and `A_numbers` columns in the initial data frame that are
adjacent to each occurence of `item[x]` in column `A`.

The final data frame should look like this:

```
df_final<-data.frame(site=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B"), A=c("item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item3"),
                      A_weight=c(4.2,4.2,6.1,6.4,8.5), A_numbers=c(1,2,8,5,2), item1_weight=c(4.2,4.2, NA, NA, NA),
                     item1_numbers=c(1,2, NA, NA, NA), item2_weight=c(NA, NA, 6.1, 6.4, NA),
                     item2_numbers=c(NA, NA, 8, 5, NA), item3_weight=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.5),
                     item3_numbers=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2))
```

I have tried several approaches using the reshape package and the match function but I feel I seem to not be making any progress (i.e. i get no decent result...). Given that I have a quite big list of "items" in my original dataset this is not a procedure to be done manually. Any assistance would be much appreciated as I am quite new to R and I could use some guidance. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using reshape2 append a column of row numbers, melt this into long form and then use `dcast` to convert to wide form merging with the original data frame and dropping the row numbers.  Finally fix up the names:

```
library(reshape2)

df.row <- cbind(row = 1:nrow(df), df)
m <- melt(df.row, id = 1:3)
wide <- merge(df.row, dcast(m, row ~ A + variable))[-1]
setNames(wide, sub("_A_", "_", names(wide)))
```

The last line gives:

```
  site     A A_weight A_numbers item1_weight item1_numbers item2_weight
1    A item1      4.2         1          4.2             1           NA
2    A item1      4.2         2          4.2             2           NA
3    B item2      6.1         8           NA            NA          6.1
4    C item2      6.4         5           NA            NA          6.4
5    B item3      8.5         2           NA            NA           NA
  item2_numbers item3_weight item3_numbers
1            NA           NA            NA
2            NA           NA            NA
3             8           NA            NA
4             5           NA            NA
5            NA          8.5             2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach but I'm sure there's better ways:

```
dat <- lapply(unique(df$A), function(x) {
    out <- df$A == x
    dat <- matrix(rep(NA,2*nrow(df)), nrow = nrow(df))
    dat[out, 1] <- df[out, 3]
    dat[out, 2] <- df[out, 4]
    colnames(dat) <- paste(x, c("weight", "numbers"), sep="_")
    dat
})

data.frame(df, do.call(cbind, dat))

## > data.frame(df, do.call(cbind, dat))
##   site     A A_weight A_numbers item1_weight item1_numbers item2_weight item2_numbers item3_weight item3_numbers
## 1    A item1      4.2         1          4.2             1           NA            NA           NA            NA
## 2    A item1      4.2         2          4.2             2           NA            NA           NA            NA
## 3    B item2      6.1         8           NA            NA          6.1             8           NA            NA
## 4    C item2      6.4         5           NA            NA          6.4             5           NA            NA
## 5    B item3      8.5         2           NA            NA           NA            NA          8.5             2
```

Answer (score 0):

Base reshape should be able to do it. If you want the A_weight and A_number variables you can add those in manually or there is probably an option to hold onto them in the reshape() call (I just didn't see it when glancing at the documentation).

```
> df<-data.frame(site=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B"), A=c("item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item3"),
+                A_weight=c(4.2,4.2,6.1,6.4,8.5), A_numbers=c(1,2,8,5,2))
> 
> (df_final <- reshape(df,idvar=c("site","A_numbers","A_weight"),timevar="A",direction="wide",v.names=c("A_numbers","A_weight")))
  site A_numbers.item1 A_weight.item1 A_numbers.item2 A_weight.item2 A_numbers.item3 A_weight.item3
1    A               1            4.2              NA             NA              NA             NA
2    A               2            4.2              NA             NA              NA             NA
3    B              NA             NA               8            6.1              NA             NA
4    C              NA             NA               5            6.4              NA             NA
5    B              NA             NA              NA             NA               2            8.5
```